# Parameters affect time complexity[Python]

Tags: parameters, time-complexity

I was wondering if the number of parameters and its return values will actually affect time complexity of a function?
For example if I implemented an O(N) algorithm but the function I have defined takes in 6 parameters and return 3 values. Will time complexity still be O(N)? Sorry if this is a silly question. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That depends entirely on how the parameters are used. No, there isn't a direct correlation between the number of parameters and complexity.

For example:

```
function someFun(par1, par2, par3, par4, par5) {
    return true;
}
```

The function runs in constant time, despite having 5 parameters,

```
function someFun2(par1) {
    for (var i = 0; i < par1; i++) {
        // Do something with i
    } 
}
```

While this is linear with respect to `par1`, despite only having 1 parameter.